# Moving EC2 Ubuntu Laravel 5.6 Public images folder files to EC2

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I have a large number of images that I had stored originally in the public folder of my EC2 Ubuntu implementation.   I want to move these images to EC2 to improve the performance and increase disk space.  Files are in a directory and sub directories under it. How do I migrate the images to EC2 without changing the path in my scripts.   The files are available to unauthenticated users.
Will it be the soft link as ln-s for the whole directory?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend moving it to S3 instead of an EC2 server.

Moving these files to another EC2 server would required you to change your scripts as you can't do symbolic links to another EC2 server (ln -s)

Comment: Unfortunately no. But this is a more ideal setup specially if you want to free up disk space on your instance as S3's purpose is to store static resources. You just need to plan how to change your code to migrate your static assets. You would also want to consider how to put all static resources on S3 from here on out. I think it's the best practice.